# Use an array of values to query mongodb database using flask mongoengine/pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a collection that has multiple fields that can be queried to return a document. I can easily use one field at a time to query the database, is it possible to use multiple search values from a combination of fields to search for documents? Using a search field, a user would enter multiple values.

My approach is to add the values to an array and send this to an api which would use the values to query the database.
Here is some sample code:

Model of Collection in db

```
class Reports(db.Document):
    id_no = db.StringField()
    fullname = db.StringField()
    position = db.StringField()
    phonenumber = db.ListField(db.StringField())
    check_in = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    meta = {'collection': 'Reports'}
```

The user's search input can be one of or a combination of the fields which would be added to an array as they're entered. Sample input:

```
{
    "id_no": "2", 
    "fullname":"John Doe",
    "check_in": "Thu Apr 16 2020",
    "position": "Clerk",
    "phonenumber" = ["12345", "54321"]

}
```

The code to handle this would look something like:

```
    def get(self):
        try:
            body = request.get_json() #get the input

            search_fields = Reports.objects.filter(body).to_json() #This is where I will execute the query but I'm not sure how to approach this properly.
            return Response(search_fields, mimetype="application/json", status=200)
```

Using the input, I want to search the database for documents that match. Is this the best approach for searching multiple fields with multiple values in mongodb using flask-mongoengine or pymongo to query? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you post a sample of you collection?

Comment: @ngShravil.py sorry, I fixed the terminology in my post, please see above.

Comment: @blazedtrailz You have mentioned only the fields (and values) you will be using in a query. A query's filter can have operators like `$and`, `$or`, `$in`, `$ne`, etc., and even a combination of then. So, you need to be sure what the query filters are (combination of fields and operators) - is it always an equality condition. Also, note that for efficient queries, appropriate indexes are to be created on the fields.

Comment: @prasad_ Yes, I'm aware. I believe the query would be complicated with that approach, for example, the user enters a combination of values between 1 and 5(max number of fields), accounting for all the possible combinations let's just say would be around at least around !5 (120)... maybe my train of thought is on the wrong road.

Comment: You have to change your check_in date to mongoengine datetime, it won't work without that. 
If user enters a lot of values then you have to define what should be unique, choosing a unique parameter to start your query narrows down a lot of work.

Comment: @overflow95 Ignoring those extra conventions, I'm more focused on executing the search query so I am accounting for formats that the database would understand. The user has specific fields to enter certain kinds of data. For example, a keyword textfield on the gui  represents phonenumbers, a datepicker for checked_in, another keyword textfield for position and another two for fullname and Id_no. Kinda like a form. The parameters are unique but the combinations are not. The combination can be any or all of these 5.